# How to use Jquery mobile panels into twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am building a website using twitter bootstrap v3.0.0 and i want to add a side-panel (pannel from the right side of the screen), and i found out that i can do that with jquery mobile. The problem is that `jquery mobile ruins all my css`, so my question is : `can i import just a part of jquery mobile ?` just the pannels ? hoping that my css won't be crashed after that?

If yes, please tell me how to do that ! Thanks

Note: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/ (this is the pannel i like to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will it be ok if you can use other jQuery panel plugins. such as:

http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/

http://designhuntr.com/15-slide-panel-jquery-plugins/

Comment: This works but i have one more question. The panel content option is only remote from another file? Can not be a div from the same file?

Comment: http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/ is perfect, but it loads just external file, isnt any option to load from a local element? If yes i will rate your answere

Comment: I've added the answer. see if this helps

Comment: You might know the answere to this question also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768363/how-to-access-colapse-function-inside-codebomber-slidepanel

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution -- you can set your content in Bootstrap columns and then use jquery to toggle the classes and animate via CSS (or jQuery). Here's a version using Bootstrap 2.x, but the principle is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/mark47/x8S2q/

Animate the `divs` with css:

```
.row div {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
}
```

And toggle column width classes:

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
    $('#colMain').toggleClass('span12 span9');
    $('#colPush').toggleClass('span0 span3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/

I don't see such option for load content from local element. I've changed some code in the plugin source file. now u can load text from a local element.

```
<a href="#" data-slidepanel="panel">Show Panel</a>

<div id="panel-content" style="display:none;">
    This is the content of the panel.
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slidepanel.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel({
              orientation: 'right',
              mode: 'overlay'
         });
    });
</script>
```

And in the **jquery.slidepanel.js** file remove these lines (line number 100-105):

```
$('.inner .wrapper', this.$panel).html('').load(href, function() {
     // remove the loading indicator
     base.$panel.removeClass('loading');
     // set the current loaded URL to the target URL
     base.$panel.data('slidepanel-loaded', href);
});
```

instead add this:

```
$('.inner .wrapper', this.$panel).html($('#panel-content').html());
base.$panel.removeClass('loading');
base.$panel.data('slidepanel-loaded', href);
```

If you need more specific here is the link of the entire modified file:

http://pastebin.com/ZsiFFm52